# Evaluating Nginx Plus R7 Performance

Tags: nginx

I am evaluating the Nginx Plus R7 commercial version and seems it has significant performance improvements than it's previous versions but still there are some Java runtime libraries  which gives high performance than Nginx for simple proxy scenarios.

Following are the configuration I add and I have enabled the thread pools , socket shading as well.

```
 user  nginx;
       worker_processes  auto;
        events {
            worker_connections  100000;
            use epoll;
            multi_accept on;
        }
        http {
            include       mime.types;
            default_type  application/octet-stream;
            sendfile        on;
            keepalive_timeout  6000;
           keepalive_requests 100000;
            access_log off;
            tcp_nopush on;
            tcp_nodelay on;
           open_file_cache max=9000000 inactive=20s;
           open_file_cache_valid 30s;
           open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
           open_file_cache_errors on;
           reset_timedout_connection on;
           client_body_timeout 10;
           send_timeout 2;
          gzip on;
          gzip_min_length 10240;
          gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
         gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml;
         gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
            server {
                listen       9090  reuseport  backlog=8192;
                server_name  localhost;
                location / {
                 aio threads;
                proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
                 proxy_set_header Connection "";
                 proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    if ( $route_id = r1 ) {
     proxy_pass http://10.100.5.98:9000/service;
}

                }
     error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
                location = /50x.html {
                    root   html;
                }
            }
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
    }
```

Are there any other parameters that need to enabled from Nginx level and Kernel level parameters are also being set up.